# Como executar multiplos comandos (cmd) c#?

Tags: c#

Bom pessoal, preciso de uma aplicação que capture o input e o output, de forma com que após a execução de um comando o mesmo "prompt" não seja fechado.

Atualmente consigo executar comandos e capturar o output de forma isolada. Segue a função que eu fiz:

```
public string Cmd(string comand)
    {
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c {0}", comand);
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.Start();

        string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        if (output == "") { output = "Comando executado"; }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: A ideia é manter o _prompt_ aberto e a receber comandos do "outro lado" até dar algum sinal para fechar?

Comment: Simm @JoãoMartins

Answer (score 0):

Não está perfeito, precisa de uns ajustes.
Não sei se é exactamente isso que precisa.

```
    static Process execCommand = new Process();
    static void Cmd2(string comando, string argumentos)
    {
        string saida = "";



        execCommand.StartInfo.FileName = comando;
        execCommand.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //  execCommand.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        execCommand.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentos;
        execCommand.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        try
        {
            execCommand.Start();
            saida = execCommand.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(saida);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }




    }

    static void IniciarCmd2(int numeroDeComandos)
    {
        string[] comandos = new string[numeroDeComandos];
        string[] argumentos = new string[numeroDeComandos];

        for (int i = 0; i < comandos.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite o comando n#" + (i+1));
            comandos[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Digite o argumento n#" + (i+1));
            argumentos[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < comandos.Length; i++)
        {
            Cmd2(comandos[i], argumentos[i]);

        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        Console.WriteLine("Quantos comandos pretende executar?");


        IniciarCmd2(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));



        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Então um process com vários argumentos eu até consegui. O meu grande problema é que precisaria executar um argumento de cada vez, pegar o output e só então executar o próximo comando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar unir os comandos usando '&':

```
string cmdText = "/C primeiroCommando&segundoCommando";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmdText);
```

Caso nao funcione, sugiro criar um arquivo em lotes (*.bat) temporário e chamá-lo pelo cmd.exe usando o Process.Start(). O arquivo em lotes executará todos os comandos em um mesmo processo, permitindo que você capture o output.``